# text file cleaning, formatting and alignment

Tags: python, string, list

I'm new to python and I'd like to clean and reformat a list in python3
from:

```
[['', '\xa0', '', ''], ['First Standard', 'First Flex', 'Business 
Standard','Business Flex', 'Economy standard', 'Economy Flex', 'Economy 
Saver', 'Economy Superdeal'], ['Class', 'P/F', 'A', 'C/D', ' Z/J', 'W/Y/B/M 
', 'H/K/L', 'Q/G/V/E', 'S/T/U/N'], ['Change Fee\nIn']]
```

to

```
['First Standard', 'First Flex', 'Business Standard', 'Business Flex', 
'Economy standard', 'Economy Flex', 'Economy Saver', 'Economy Superdeal'], 
['Class','P/F', 'A', 'C/D', ' Z/J', 'W/Y/B/M ', 'H/K/L', 'Q/G/V/E', 
'S/T/U/N']
```

Comment: Indent code lines by 4 spaces to format them nicer for StackOverflow. Also, https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Ok i will do that

Comment: Those two are not the same lists, and the latter one is even invalid syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a not particularly clean, but self-explanatory way:

```
old = [['', '\xa0', '', ''], ['First Standard', 'First Flex', 'Business Standard', 'Business Flex', 'Economy standard', 'Economy Flex', 'Economy Saver', 'Economy Superdeal'], ['Class', 'P/F', 'A', 'C/D', ' Z/J', 'W/Y/B/M ', 'H/K/L', 'Q/G/V/E', 'S/T/U/N'], ['Change Fee\nIn']]

new = []
for old_element in old:
    new_element = []

    for string in old_element:
        stripped = string.strip()

        if stripped:
            new_element.append(stripped)

    if new_element:
        new.append(new_element)

print new
```

**Edit:**

Still waiting on a better explanation of the problem, but if you just want to remove the first and last elements, you can either do as @salparadise said, or else something like the following, which is a bit more general:

```
old = [['', '\xa0', '', ''], ['First Standard', 'First Flex', 'Business Standard', 'Business Flex', 'Economy standard', 'Economy Flex', 'Economy Saver', 'Economy Superdeal'], ['Class', 'P/F', 'A', 'C/D', ' Z/J', 'W/Y/B/M ', 'H/K/L', 'Q/G/V/E', 'S/T/U/N'], ['Change Fee\nIn']]

# 1 means the second element of the list, because 0 is the first.
# -1 means "one element back from the end of the list".
new = old[1:-1]
```

Comment: Just realized that my version leaves in the last element, while his desired version does not. Not sure exactly what he wants yet, so I'll wait to edit until he updates his question.

Comment: your version works but I'd like to remove the last element like you said . Thanks

Comment: @Ade Can you explain the criteria you have for elements to be removed? Please edit your question to explain what it means to you to "clean up" the list.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want two separate lists and your first list is:

```
[['', '\xa0', '', ''],
 ['First Standard',
  'First Flex',
  'Business Standard',
  'Business Flex',
  'Economy standard',
  'Economy Flex',
  'Economy Saver',
  'Economy Superdeal'],
 ['Class',
  'P/F',
  'A',
  'C/D',
  ' Z/J',
  'W/Y/B/M ',
  'H/K/L',
  'Q/G/V/E',
  'S/T/U/N'],
 ['Change Fee\nIn']]
```

You can use python's unpacking magic to just grab the inner lists and dump it into two different lists:

```
 _, first, second, _ = bad_formatted_list

In [149]: first, second
Out[149]:
(['First Standard',
  'First Flex',
  'Business Standard',
  'Business Flex',
  'Economy standard',
  'Economy Flex',
  'Economy Saver',
  'Economy Superdeal'],
 ['Class',
  'P/F',
  'A',
  'C/D',
  ' Z/J',
  'W/Y/B/M ',
  'H/K/L',
  'Q/G/V/E',
  'S/T/U/N'])
```